# Editable field saved to database

Tags: html, angular, savechanges

I've got this editable field. I need it to save the new data and store it in the database.
HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="groupedVolumes">
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let model of groupKeys() | slice:-3" >
                            <tr>
                                <th class="model">{{ carValues(model)[0].model }}</th>
                                <ng-container *ngFor="let value of carValues(model)">
                                    <td contenteditable='true' class="data">
                                        {{ value.scheduledVolume }}
                                    </td>
                                </ng-container>
                            </tr>
                        </ng-container>                
                    </ng-container>
```

The HTML data shows the editable field.
This is the button to save with:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <button
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-success mx-1"
        onclick="saveData()">Save
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good approach.
Use input (probably type="text") for input using the angular form api, then you can store the new values in database on completion.

Comment: Updated question with save button

Comment: Same answer. You need to bind the user input to your variable. Otherwise the change the user makes won't be saved. For that, use inputs and angular's forms.